# rolling computation for following or previous values in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table, compare, rolling-computation

I have a data.table `DT` with 3 columns, `Zeit`, `Spuer` and `Eingriff`.

```
DT <- data.table(Zeit = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), 
                 Spuer = c(45, 45, 32, 25, 30, 44, 34, 42, 44), 
                 Eingriff = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0))
```

I want to find out if `Eingriff == 1` and one of the next 3 values of `Spuer < 30`. If it is TRUE then `Eingriff == 1` else `Eingriff == 0`. For my real data I check if the next 20 values or more in `Spuer` are smaller than 30, so a solution like lead(Spuer, 1), lead(Spuer, 2) etc. is not a good solution.

I already tried to implement a solution with `frollapply` and `shift` but couldn't make it work.

In the end the result should look like this:

```
res <- data.table(Zeit = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), 
                  Spuer = c(45, 45, 32, 25, 30, 44, 34, 42, 44), 
                  Eingriff = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option using `sapply` :

We first find out indices where `Eingriff == 1` and for each of those indices check if `any` of the value in the `window` is less than 30.

```
library(data.table)

window <- 3
inds <- which(DT$Eingriff == 1)

DT[inds, Eingriff := as.integer(sapply(inds, function(x) 
                              any(DT$Spuer[x:(x+window - 1)] < 30)))]

DT
#   Zeit Spuer Eingriff
#1:    1    45        0
#2:    2    45        0
#3:    3    32        1
#4:    4    25        0
#5:    5    30        0
#6:    6    44        0
#7:    7    34        0
#8:    8    42        0
#9:    9    44        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using non-equi join:

```
k <- 3L
DT[, c("start", "end") := .(.I, .I + k)]
DT[Eingriff==1L, Eingriff :=
    DT[.SD, on=.(start>start, start<=end), by=.EACHI, +any(x.Spuer < 30)]$V1
]
```

output:

```
   Zeit Spuer Eingriff start end
1:    1    45        0     1   4
2:    2    45        0     2   5
3:    3    32        1     3   6
4:    4    25        0     4   7
5:    5    30        0     5   8
6:    6    44        0     6   9
7:    7    34        0     7  10
8:    8    42        0     8  11
9:    9    44        0     9  12
```